# how does e.preventDefault(); work if the event is button.click in js?

Tags: javascript

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button> 

<script>   
    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hello1');
    }, false);
</script>
```

I am trying to understand `e.preventDefault();`, I know If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. So my question is:

For above codes, it seems `e.preventDefault();` does not do anything here. so what is the default action of above event:`getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click`?

Comment: A button type `button` has no default event AFAIK.

Comment: What is it you're trying to prevent?

Comment: What makes you think that `e.preventDefault()` isn't doing anything?

Comment: either you unbind click event for the button or put a return true after your e.preventDefault().

Comment: e.preventDefault() is to prevent a default browser action from happening.If it's a clickable link,it will not go to the link.But right now,there is no event being triggered,so nothing happens.A button even event is only triggered if some event call is added.If you do this for a submit button however,the default is to submit the form but if e.preventDefault() is added,it will not submit the form.

Comment: If that's your code, it's a parse error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default action of an element in HTML is defined in the HTML5 specification. The [interactive content section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content) describes how to respond to interaction, including what to do when an activation (click) event is and is not cancelled, and the individual interactive elements (listed at the top of the section) have defined activation behaviours. The [activation behaviour for `<button>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) says (emphasis added):

> When a button element is not disabled, its activation behavior element is to run the steps defined in the following list for the current state of the element's type attribute:
>
> Submit Button
>
> If the element has a form owner, the element must submit the form owner from the button element.
>
> Reset Button
>
> If the element has a form owner, the element must reset the form owner.
>
> **Button**
>
> **Do nothing.**

Answer (score -3):

e.preventDefault() prevent the event from traveling up further. For example, in the above code if you have a onclick handler on the  element, then without e.preventDefault() the  element's onclick handler will be called. The button's onclick event will be always fired because you can't stop something that has already happened, but you can stop events that has yet to happen --- in this case the body's onclick event.

Comment: I think you're confusing `preventDefault()` with `stopPropagation()`