# addEventListener doesn't get assigned to a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I don't understand why my first button can have an `eventlistener` assigned, but my second one won't.  There are no error messages and I'm able to access its value and even change its style via `element.style.border="2px red solid"`  for example.

```js
const recipeTypeMenuContainer = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu-container"),
      recipeTypeMenuSection = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu-section"),
      breakfast_menuButton = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu_breakfast"),
      appetizer_menuButton = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu_appetizer"),
      entrees_menuButton = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu_entrees"),
      dessert_menuButton = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu_dessert"),
      menuButtons = [breakfast_menuButton,appetizer_menuButton,entrees_menuButton,dessert_menuButton];

////////////RECIPE or BLOG section///////////////
////////****works***///////////////////

enterRecipePicture.addEventListener('click',function(){
    recipeOrBlogContainer.classList.add('js-fadehide');
    searchbarContainer.classList.add('js-fadehide');    
})
 
////////////TYPE OF RECIPE section///////////////
///***doesn't work and doesn't throw error**////

breakfast_menuButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    recipeTypeMenuContainer.style.border = "2px red solid";
})
```

```html
<div class="recipe-type-menu-container">
    <div class="recipe-type-menu-row"></div>
    <div class="recipe-type-menu-row">
      <center>
        <form class="recipe-type-menu-section" action="recipe-blog.php" method="POST">
          <button type="submit" class="recipe-type-menu_breakfast" id="recipetype_breakfast" name="recipe-type" value="breakfast" >breakfast</button>
          <button type="submit" class="recipe-type-menu_appetizer" id="recipetype_appetizer" name="recipe-type" value="appetizer">appetizer</button>
          <button type="submit" class="recipe-type-menu_entrees" id="recipetype_entrees" name="recipe-type" value="entrees">entrees</button>
          <button type="submit" class="recipe-type-menu_dessert" id="recipetype_dessert" name="recipe-type" value="dessert">dessert</button>
        </form>
      </center>
    </div>
    <!------ recipe-type-menu-row ----->
    <div class="recipe-type-menu-row"></div>

  </div>
```

Comment: `enterRecipePicture` doesn't seem to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `type="submit"` on your buttons, so when its clicked it submit the form, you need to add `e.preventDefault()` ( check this link [how-does-e-preventdefault-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438514/how-does-e-preventdefault-work-if-the-event-is-button-click-in-js) ) or use `type="button"` if you dont want the button to submit the form

```js
const recipeTypeMenuContainer = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu-container"),
      recipeTypeMenuSection = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu-section"),
      breakfast_menuButton = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu_breakfast"),
      appetizer_menuButton = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu_appetizer"),
      entrees_menuButton = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu_entrees"),
      dessert_menuButton = document.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu_dessert"),
      menuButtons = [breakfast_menuButton,appetizer_menuButton,entrees_menuButton,dessert_menuButton];

////////////RECIPE or BLOG section///////////////
////////****works***///////////////////
/*
enterRecipePicture.addEventListener('click',function(){
    recipeOrBlogContainer.classList.add('js-fadehide');
    searchbarContainer.classList.add('js-fadehide');    
})
*/
////////////TYPE OF RECIPE section///////////////
///***doesn't work and doesn't throw error**////

breakfast_menuButton.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    recipeTypeMenuContainer.style.border = "2px red solid";
})
```

```html
<div class="recipe-type-menu-container">
    <div class="recipe-type-menu-row"></div>
    <div class="recipe-type-menu-row">
      <center>
        <form class="recipe-type-menu-section" action="recipe-blog.php" method="POST">
          <button type="button" class="recipe-type-menu_breakfast" id="recipetype_breakfast" name="recipe-type" value="breakfast" >breakfast</button>
          <button type="submit" class="recipe-type-menu_appetizer" id="recipetype_appetizer" name="recipe-type" value="appetizer">appetizer</button>
          <button type="submit" class="recipe-type-menu_entrees" id="recipetype_entrees" name="recipe-type" value="entrees">entrees</button>
          <button type="submit" class="recipe-type-menu_dessert" id="recipetype_dessert" name="recipe-type" value="dessert">dessert</button>
        </form>
      </center>
    </div>
    <!------ recipe-type-menu-row ----->
    <div class="recipe-type-menu-row"></div>

  </div>
```